# How to grab text from a webpage and set the document.title to it?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm on a game site where the page titles do not reflect the game titles but rather the site name and description of the site. Each game name appears on their page like so:

```
<div id="gr-header">
   <div>
      <h1><a href='/games/'>Games Room</a> - Some Game Name Here</h1>
   </div>
   <div>
      some other stuff
   </div>
</div>
```

Right now I'm manually matching the game id, in the URL, to the respective game title and doing the following where `idlist` is an array containing a subset of the game ids, that I bothered to check, and `gamelist` is an array containing the respective game names in corresponding order.

```
for (i=0; i < idlist.length; i++)
{ 
   if (gameid[0] == idlist[i])
   { 
      document.title = gamelist[i];
      break;
   }
}
```

However this is inelegant as there are way too many games to manually list them. How can I grab the "Some Game Name Here" text from a webpage and store said text in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelector) and a simple [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var nameElement = document.querySelector ("#gr-header div h1");
var gameName    = nameElement.textContent.replace (/^.*\s-\s/, "");
document.title  = gameName;
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If you really want one-liner code it is: `document.title  = document.querySelector ("#gr-header div h1").textContent.replace (/^.*\s-\s/, "");` ... ... However, splitting it is the smarter way to go, it helps with debugging, maintenance, and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML structure you posted, try this

```
var title = $('#gr-header h1').clone().children().remove().end().text().replace(/^[\W]+/, '');
document.title = title;
```

That gets the direct text of the `h1` (i.e. not including the text of its child `a`).

(The REGEX removes the '- ' at the start of the game name. Adjust/remove as required.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcMTt/1/

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I tried to print the variable "title" (even tried changing the variable name) but nothing came out :( Pity, because I do love one liner code! So beautiful!

Comment: Works fine for me - here's the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/gcMTt/1/. (JSFiddle uses frames so you'll have to inspect the DOM of the output frame to see the changed title. Or, better still, try the code yourself. Confirmed works for me in 3 browsers.)